# Create a UICollectionView with a reversed flow layout

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I want to create a view that resembles a chat view, where the newest message appears at the bottom of the screen. I would like the `UICollectionViewCells` to be 'pinned' to the bottom of the screen - the opposite of what the default flow layout does. How can I do this?

I've got this code from another stackoverflow answer, but it doesn't work with variable height items (which it needs to):

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class InvertedStackLayout: UICollectionViewLayout {
    let cellHeight: CGFloat = 100 // Your cell height here...

    override func prepare() {
        super.prepare()
    }

    override func layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {
        var layoutAttrs = [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]()

        if let collectionView = self.collectionView {
            for section in 0 ..< collectionView.numberOfSections {
                if let numberOfSectionItems = numberOfItemsInSection(section) {
                    for item in 0 ..< numberOfSectionItems {
                        let indexPath = IndexPath(item: item, section: section)
                        let layoutAttr = layoutAttributesForItem(at: indexPath)

                        if let layoutAttr = layoutAttr, layoutAttr.frame.intersects(rect) {
                            layoutAttrs.append(layoutAttr)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return layoutAttrs
    }

    override func layoutAttributesForItem(at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes? {
        let layoutAttr = UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes(forCellWith: indexPath)
        let contentSize = self.collectionViewContentSize

        layoutAttr.frame = CGRect(
            x: 0, y: contentSize.height - CGFloat(indexPath.item + 1) * cellHeight,
            width: contentSize.width, height: cellHeight)

        return layoutAttr
    }

    func numberOfItemsInSection(_ section: Int) -> Int? {
        if let collectionView = self.collectionView,
            let numSectionItems = collectionView.dataSource?.collectionView(collectionView, numberOfItemsInSection: section)
        {
            return numSectionItems
        }

        return 0
    }

    override var collectionViewContentSize: CGSize {
        get {
            var height: CGFloat = 0
            var bounds: CGRect = .zero

            if let collectionView = self.collectionView {
                for section in 0 ..< collectionView.numberOfSections {
                    if let numItems = numberOfItemsInSection(section) {
                        height += CGFloat(numItems) * cellHeight
                    }
                }

                bounds = collectionView.bounds
            }

            return CGSize(width: bounds.width, height: max(height, bounds.height))
        }
    }

    override func shouldInvalidateLayout(forBoundsChange newBounds: CGRect) -> Bool {
        if let oldBounds = self.collectionView?.bounds,
            oldBounds.width != newBounds.width || oldBounds.height != newBounds.height
        {
            return true
        }

        return false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Flip your collectionView with a CGAffineTransform so that it starts at the bottom.

```
collectionView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1, y: -1)
```

The only problem now is that all your cells display upside down. You then apply the transform to each cell to flip it back upright.

```
class InvertedCollectionViewFlowLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout {

    // inverting the transform in the layout, rather than directly on the cell, 
    // is the only way I've found to prevent cells from flipping during animated
    // cell updates

    override func layoutAttributesForItem(at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes? {
        let attrs = super.layoutAttributesForItem(at: indexPath)
        attrs?.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1, y: -1)
        return attrs
    }

    override func layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {
        let attrsList = super.layoutAttributesForElements(in: rect)
        if let list = attrsList {
            for i in 0..<list.count {
                list[i].transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1, y: -1)
            }
        }
        return attrsList
    }
}
```

Comment: just be sure to adjust your data set to ensure its in the proper order. Same goes for any 'scrollToIndex' calls and cell positioning designations.

Answer (score 1):

UICollectionView with a reversed flow layout and dynamic cell and header height.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class InvertedFlowLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout {

    override func prepare() {
        super.prepare()
    }

    override func layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {
        guard super.layoutAttributesForElements(in: rect) != nil else { return nil }
        var attributesArrayNew = [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]()

        if let collectionView = self.collectionView {
            for section in 0 ..< collectionView.numberOfSections {
                for item in 0 ..< collectionView.numberOfItems(inSection: section) {
                    let indexPathCurrent = IndexPath(item: item, section: section)
                    if let attributeCell = layoutAttributesForItem(at: indexPathCurrent) {
                        if attributeCell.frame.intersects(rect) {
                            attributesArrayNew.append(attributeCell)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            for section in 0 ..< collectionView.numberOfSections {
                let indexPathCurrent = IndexPath(item: 0, section: section)
                if let attributeKind = layoutAttributesForSupplementaryView(ofKind: UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader, at: indexPathCurrent) {
                    attributesArrayNew.append(attributeKind)
                }
            }
        }

        return attributesArrayNew
    }

    override func layoutAttributesForSupplementaryView(ofKind elementKind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes? {
        let attributeKind = UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes(forSupplementaryViewOfKind: elementKind, with: indexPath)

        if let collectionView = self.collectionView {
            var fullHeight: CGFloat = 0.0

            for section in 0 ..< indexPath.section + 1 {
                for item in 0 ..< collectionView.numberOfItems(inSection: section) {
                    let indexPathCurrent = IndexPath(item: item, section: section)
                    fullHeight += cellHeight(indexPathCurrent) + minimumLineSpacing
                }
            }

            attributeKind.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: collectionViewContentSize.height - fullHeight - CGFloat(indexPath.section + 1) * headerHeight(indexPath.section) - sectionInset.bottom + minimumLineSpacing/2, width: collectionViewContentSize.width, height: headerHeight(indexPath.section))
        }

        return attributeKind
    }

    override func layoutAttributesForItem(at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes? {
        let attributeCell = UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes(forCellWith: indexPath)

        if let collectionView = self.collectionView {
            var fullHeight: CGFloat = 0.0

            for section in 0 ..< indexPath.section + 1 {
                for item in 0 ..< collectionView.numberOfItems(inSection: section) {
                    let indexPathCurrent = IndexPath(item: item, section: section)
                    fullHeight += cellHeight(indexPathCurrent) + minimumLineSpacing

                    if section == indexPath.section && item == indexPath.item {
                        break
                    }
                }
            }

            attributeCell.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: collectionViewContentSize.height - fullHeight + minimumLineSpacing - CGFloat(indexPath.section) * headerHeight(indexPath.section) - sectionInset.bottom, width: collectionViewContentSize.width, height: cellHeight(indexPath) )
        }

        return attributeCell
    }

    override var collectionViewContentSize: CGSize {
        get {
            var height: CGFloat = 0.0
            var bounds = CGRect.zero

            if let collectionView = self.collectionView {
                for section in 0 ..< collectionView.numberOfSections {
                    for item in 0 ..< collectionView.numberOfItems(inSection: section) {
                        let indexPathCurrent = IndexPath(item: item, section: section)
                        height += cellHeight(indexPathCurrent) + minimumLineSpacing
                    }
                }

                height += sectionInset.bottom + CGFloat(collectionView.numberOfSections) * headerHeight(0)
                bounds = collectionView.bounds
            }

            return CGSize(width: bounds.width, height: max(height, bounds.height))
        }
    }

    override func shouldInvalidateLayout(forBoundsChange newBounds: CGRect) -> Bool {
        if let oldBounds = self.collectionView?.bounds,
            oldBounds.width != newBounds.width || oldBounds.height != newBounds.height {
            return true
        }

        return false
    }

    func cellHeight(_ indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        if let collectionView = self.collectionView, let delegateFlowLayout = collectionView.delegate as? UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
            let size = delegateFlowLayout.collectionView!(collectionView, layout: self, sizeForItemAt: indexPath)
            return size.height
        }

        return 0
    }

    func headerHeight(_ section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        if let collectionView = self.collectionView, let delegateFlowLayout = collectionView.delegate as? UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
            let size = delegateFlowLayout.collectionView!(collectionView, layout: self, referenceSizeForHeaderInSection: section)
            return size.height
        }

        return 0
    }
}
```

Comment: how to use that afterwards?

Answer (score -2):

you could rotate(transform) collectionView 180 degrees so top will be at the bottom and rotate(transform) each cell 180 to make them look normal.